# Unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable after Grails update

Tags: maven, grails, grails-cache

I'm upgrading Grails from `2.1.0` to `2.3.7`. I have a Maven-based project. For `2.1.0` the command `mvn clean install` runs without error. For `2.3.7` it gives:

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/freyja/fbc/fbc/search-web-app/grails-app/services/pl/psnc/dlteam/fbc2/services/CacheService.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable
@ line 4, column 1.
import grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable
^

/home/freyja/fbc/fbc/search-web-app/grails-app/services/pl/psnc/dlteam/fbc2/services/CacheService.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cache.CachePut
@ line 3, column 1.
import grails.plugin.cache.CachePut
^
```

I tried newest version of Grails `cache` plugin - `1.1.1` and the one that worked ok with Grails `2.1.0`, which is `cache 1.0.0`. The error is the same.

I checked how this file `CacheService.groovy` looks and it indeed has these two imports and appears to need them. I checked that `cache` plugin zip had been downloaded to `.m2` folder.

I include `cache` plugin in `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

When I run `grails compile` there also is no error and you can also run the application with `grails run-app`. But it would be nice to have it working in Maven, as it worked before. Could you please help me with this?

I have one additional question that maybe will allow me to understand what is happening: if I use Maven are dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy` still important? Should I remove them? Because now we have two sets of dependencies to maintain in the project and it does not look like a proper thing.

**Edit:**

`BuildConfig.groovy` looks like this:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" 
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    pom true
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    def gebVersion = "0.7.2"

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        compile 'org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:4.0.3'
        compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.5'
        compile 'org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:4.3.0'
        test 'co.freeside:betamax:1.1.2'
        test "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"

    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.12"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        test ":spock:0.7"
        test ":geb:$gebVersion"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"

        compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    }
}

grails.war.resources = {stagingDir ->
    delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/pl/psnc/dlteam/fbc2/utils/iso693_2")
}
```

**But is it used at all for maven build?** If so, why do I have to include plugins in `pom.xml`?. This redundancy bothers me.

Comment: How does the `BuildConfig` look like?

Comment: You can remove all plugins and dependencies from `BuildConfig` as they will be referred from `pom.xml`. Do not remove BuildConfig. Specific tasks are done during war creation (grails.war.resources) which will be needed. Do a `mvn clean install` after emptying `plugins { }` and `dependencies { }`. I assume all those dependencies are already mentioned in pom file.

Comment: Also check if you are still need `ivy` in here `grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"` instead of aether.

Comment: @dmahapatro I checked how does it go when I comment out all dependencies,and plugins in `BuildConfig.groovy` and the error is the same. All packages were put to `.m2`, and `.grails` directory was not recreated. This is what I expected. I see there are is `cache-1.1.1.zip` in `.m2/repository/org/grails/plugin/cache/1.1.1/` and I checked it contains proper interfaces files inside.

Comment: @dmahapatro I checked both `ivy` and `maven`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

BuildConfig.groovy

put this line

```
dependencies {
        compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.6"

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. I also tried to put this dependency in `pom.xml`, because I would prefer to have all dependencies there, but the error is the same. Do you have any other ideas? I've been stuck with this for two weeks now.